# Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method ... on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, xml

Although this question has been asked several times none of the solutions has worked for me. I keep getting this error suddenly, and I think I might have have a problem different those others.

Here's the class thats responsible:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_car);
    }

    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    PageDownloader PDL = new PageDownloader();


    TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    TextView tv2 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    TextView tv3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    public int Distance;
    public int Mileage;
    float GasPriceMid;
    float GasPricePre;
    float GasPriceReg;
    public float Toll;
    public float Parking;
    String StringPriceReg;
    String StringPriceMid;
    String StringPricePre;
```

As well as this one:

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PriceCalculator PC = new PriceCalculator();
    //PageDownloader PDL = new PageDownloader();


    EditText et1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
    EditText et2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);
    EditText et3 = findViewById(R.id.et3);
    EditText et4 = findViewById(R.id.et4);
```

It was simply supposed to create a reference to these objects but its receiving this error:

```
    Process: com.example.ojd.pricecalculatorapp, PID: 5067
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ojd.pricecalculatorapp/com.example.ojd.pricecalculatorapp.MenuActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3418)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:231)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7422)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.example.ojd.pricecalculatorapp.PriceCalculator.<init>(PriceCalculator.java:19)
        at com.example.ojd.pricecalculatorapp.MenuActivity.<init>(MenuActivity.java:9)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3418) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:231) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7422) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

It says that the problem was (PriceCalculator.java:19) which is

```
TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
```

and (MenuActivity.java:9)

```
PriceCalculator PC = new PriceCalculator();
```

Thanks in advance and I'm hoping the answer won't just be a stupid mistake I made.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code snippet, but PriceCalculator appears to extend from AppCompatActivity.  You should never use the new operator with activities.  Doing this will cause the activity to not have the proper context set and you won't be able to use methods like findViewById().  I'm not sure why MenuActivity has an instance of another activity inside of it.  This is also a bad idea, activities should never have references to each other and should instead communicate through intents.  Fixing these two issues should make things work better.

Comment: PriceCalculator isn't supposed to be an activity, it's just a java class, so should I remove the `extends AppCompatActivty`? And the instance within the MenuActivity is used to call methods, so what should I do about that?

Comment: Correct, PriceCalculator should not extend AppCompatActivity and it should not contain references to views.  Move the TextView references into MenuActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think `TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);` should be in the onCreate method...

Try putting those in the onCreate method?

Comment: Since PriceCalculator is created with the new operator, onCreate() probably won't be called. Typically onCreate() would be the right place for those lines, but I don't think it will help given the other issues with the code.

Comment: If your price calculator is created with a 'new', assuming it is a model class, I dont think it should have those UI (TextView) and it shouldnt extends AppCompatActivity as well?
If you want to findViewById, it should have the setContentView() called!

Comment: And btw, use this if you want to change activity 
`Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class)
startActivity(i)`
Refer to this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java

Comment: yeah i know about intents but setContentView() worked at the moment, but I plan to change that later. I'm gonna try all these suggestions. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Just put all your identifications inside your Activity onCreate function. Meaning to say,

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_car);
    TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    TextView tv2 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    TextView tv3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
}
```